# Getting a JFrame to display floating on tiling window managers

Tags: java, scala, swing

I am currently writing a JVM Swing Application where the main window should only show up as a fixed size dialog. Developing this on a tiling window manager (in my case i3-wm), handles this as a tiling window. I'd like it to become floating.

In other programming languages/window frameworks this is done by setting the "Dialog" flag for the window, which tells the window manager that this window is a dialog. Unfortunately swing doesn't seem to have such an option. I also tried using a JDialog (effectively as a drop-in replacement to JFrame), but had no luck with that either.

Further research revealed a function `JFrame.setResizable`. Passing `false` to that resulted in the window showing up correctly as floating, however immediately closing a split second later. The window close handler is not called in that case. This is the closest i got to success

The code in question (scala) is

```scala
  val jframe = new JFrame()

  val size = new Dimension(310, 100)
  jframe.setMinimumSize(size)
  jframe.setMaximumSize(size)
  jframe.setPreferredSize(size)

  val layout = new GridLayout(0, 1)
  jframe.setLayout(layout)
  jframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE)

  // snip (code to add components to the JFrame)

  jframe.pack()
  jframe.setVisible(true)
```

Comment: Just a random guess: invoke [`setType`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setType(java.awt.Window.Type)) with [`Window.POPUP`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.Type.html#POPUP). Cannot test it currently.

Comment: While popup makes the window floating, it also removes the window decoration. Additionally it removes my ability to focus the window. `POPUP` seems to be intended more for things like a context menu

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem recently (I am also using `i3-wm`). I managed to create something that mimics what you are looking for using `JDialogs`. Note that I am not familiar with scala, so my solution is written in Java. I hope this will help you nonetheless.

You need to create a `JOptionPane` with your desired settings - I assume, without icon and components that accompany the default dialogs from `JOptionPane`, e.g. `MessageDialog`, `ConfirmDialog`, etc. From this, you use the `createDialog` method to create a new `JDialog` object from your `JOptionPane` object.

You can then customize and add a `JPanel` with the layout and components you need in your application. The size of the window should be set through the `JDialog` object.

Remember to dispose the dialog when it is closed. Additionally, the application did not exit for me once the dialog closed, and as such I added a listener that calls `System.exit(0)` on close.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

public class CustomDialog {

    public CustomDialog() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JDialog dialog;

        // add components to JPanel..

        // create option pane with desired settings
        JOptionPane optPane = new JOptionPane(
                "",
                JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE,
                JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION,
                new Icon() {
                    @Override
                    public void paintIcon(Component component, Graphics graphics, int i, int i1) {}

                    @Override
                    public int getIconWidth() {return 0;}

                    @Override
                    public int getIconHeight() {return 0;}
                },
                new Object[]{},
                null
        );

        dialog = optPane.createDialog(new Frame(), title);

        dialog.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));

        dialog.add(panel);

        dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        dialog.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

        dialog.pack();
        dialog.show();
    }
}
```

Launching the dialog box can be done like so

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new CustomDialog();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I did not actually see this until now, I'll check it out later. But from what i see this looks promising!

Comment: Since I made this comment I found that in JavaFX it's possible to achieve this with one line; `stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UTILITY)`. Try calling `setType(Type.UTILITY)` on your JFrame instead of my answer above (haven't tried it myself yet, so unsure if it works the same way). Let me know how it works out. :)